# can a 3rd party site's form be opened in my webpage, along with some material from my site

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I am trying to automate a repetitive job of submitting same/similar data to multiple sites... In some of these sites, I want to open the 3rd party web form in my java web app, and show a button that asks the user to "fill in " the form.

Once that button is clicked, some javascript code will fill in the various fields on that site with appropriate data... After that the end user can submit that form to its action.

What I want to know is, is it necessary to open the 3rd party site in an iframe? Is it possible to open the 3rd party page (typically a php page) directly in my web app and show button alongside it for filling it in? And once 3rd party site gives its response (to the form submission) 2 buttons should be shown in my web app- "successful submission" and "failed submission" So that the person making the submission can take a look at the response and accordingly tag the submission as success or failure.

From what I have understood, there is a need to use iframes to display the 3rd party site. Is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way to do this is using iframes.

Another alternative would be to have your server-side fetch the page from the 3rd party server, extract the relevant HTML from the page and embed it in your page.  However, this is not easy, and is liable to be fragile.  For example, the embedding may break the CSS styling or Javascript in the 3rd party page.